# Angular async form validation using Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a form validation that checks on Firebase if a username exists. If it doesn't, then the form becomes invalid.

The form validation works fine when I mock the data using an Observable. However, it doesn't work when I fetch the data from Firebase.

**This works:**

```
fromMockData(username: string): Observable<Usernames> {
  return username === 'demo' ? Observable.of({ uid: 'test' }) : Observable.of(null);
}
```

**This one doesn't:**

```
fromFirebase(username: string): Observable<Usernames> {
  return this.afs.doc(`usernames/${username}`).valueChanges();
}
```

I'm accessing both services from a validation service:

```
fromFirebase(input: FormControl): Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
    return this.service.fromFirebase(input.value).pipe(
      map(user => user ? { invalidUsername: `@${input.value} already exists` } : null),
    );
  }
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work when fetching the data from Firebase?

PS. I can see the correct value when logging `user` into the console - even when using Firebase. However, it's not returning the proper value to the form's errors properties (it only works in the first case: creating an Observable with mock data).

This is my form, btw:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [], [this.validator.fromFirebase.bind(this.validator)]],
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2f8pzp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Firebase returns a streaming of data, I need to use the [first operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) so that only the first item is emitted:

```
fromFirebase(input: FormControl): Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
  return this.service.fromFirebase(input.value).pipe(
    first(),
    map(user => user ? { invalidUsername: `@${input.value} already exists` } : null),
  );
}
```